# Store JSON inside HTMl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a jQuery script that runs on document ready and tries to get some values for configuration. I want to store this values inside JSON.

I've done this:

```
<div id="settings" style="display: none">{"name": "value"}</div>
```

However, this is not search engine friendly.

Is there another way to embed JSON inside html and then pulling with jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you including the JSON that it is visible to search engines? This is usually not a problem.

Comment: Can you include the line(s) that you're using to kick off the lightbox? I can think of a few ways to solve your problem, having the lightbox slideshow initialisation code will help people answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `<script>` element with a custom type attribute and an ID. You can use the ID to get that element and retrieve the text content.

Of course, you could just insert the JSON in with your other script, and assign it to a variable.

However, there's no guarantee that search engines will index the contents of a script element.

Instead you could just create a hidden element of some kind, with the JSON as its text content.

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep your data separate from the DOM.

Assuming that you are rendering the page(s) out from some templating system, you're going to have the same data available in the template to render the html version (which search engines read) and the data portion, which your script uses.

Its best not to pollute the namespace of the js thread running in the context of the current page. To that end, I recommend including the data in a script tag assigned to a variable that your lightbox reads after it loads.

For example:

```
<div> {name} </div>
<div> {value} </div>

<script>
    var mydata = mydata || {};
    mydata.lightbox = {
        "name": "value"
    }
</script>
```

Alternatively, if you do a xhr or jsonp request to get the json data, you can still use the mydata approach, or just work with the data directly in your lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

Why not output the data in the markup in a search engine friendly way (I guess that's important since you mention it) and access them with ordinary jquery selectors? If you need to, you could hide the data elements with CSS.

Comment: No, this is not possible. I'm just telling my lightbox script to make a slideshow and this is only possible with json so where to place it?

Comment: So you need to pass the data in an object to the plugin? Again, if SEO is important, you could just create the javascript object from the data in the markup. At least that's how I would have done it :)